# copy or share aws ami across account via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform-provider-aws

i am creating aws ami using packer and trying to copy or share aws ami across account via terraform.

ami is present in mumbai region ap-south-1 and i want to copy to hyd region ap-south-2 with tags intact .

i was checking https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ami_copy

```
resource "aws_ami_copy" "example" {
  name              = "terraform-example"
  description       = "A copy of ami-xxxxxxxx"
  source_ami_id     = "ami-xxxxxxxx"
  source_ami_region = "us-west-1"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: @Paolo No it didn't worked

Comment: Can you explain why not?

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/10132#issuecomment-713234804

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ami_users](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/plugins/builders/amazon/ebs#ami_users) directly from packer to share the image with other accounts, and you can use [ami_regions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/plugins/builders/amazon/ebs#ami_regions) to copy the image to different regions.

Comment: but my tags are not getting copied

Comment: @SatyamPandey yes, tags are copied too. Did you read the documentation?

Comment: i am using ami_regions to copy image to mutliple region , & using ami_user to share the images with other account, here is the problem when the images are getting shared it will drop the tags